# NullPointerException al utilizar g.DrawImage

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer de tarea una ventana donde mueva dos plataformas cómo para un videojuego, una que se mueva en horizontal y otro en vertical, todo esto utilizando hilos. Tengo el problema de que al correr ni siquiera se dibujan mis plataformas y me marca un `NullPinerException` en el `g.drawImage(plat, x, y, 20, 5, null);` el ultimo parámetro es el `ImageObserver` y veo que casi todos lo dejan en `Null`, agradecería mucho si me ayudasen ya que mi equipo no hace mucho.

Clase de la ventana

```
package animelem;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AnimElem extends JFrame {
    LinkedList <Plataforma> plats;

    public AnimElem() {
        initComps();
        initPlats();
    }

    public void initComps() {
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(720, 480);
    }

    public void initPlats() {
        plats = new LinkedList<>();
        plats.add(new Plataforma(200, 660, 1, this.getGraphics()));
        plats.add(new Plataforma(300, 660, 2, this.getGraphics()));

        for(Plataforma plat : plats) {
            plat.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        AnimElem v = new AnimElem();
        v.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Clase de las plataformas

```
package animelem;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Plataforma extends Thread {
    Image plat = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/plat.png")).getImage();
    Graphics g;
    int x, y, orien, distancia, total = 20, yMax = 20, yMin = 670;
    boolean izq, der, arriba, abajo;

    // orien - 1 para vertical, 2 para horizontal
    public Plataforma(int x, int y, int orien, Graphics g) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.orien = orien;
        arriba = true;
        der = true;
        distancia = 0;
        this.g = g;
    }

    public void paint() {
        g.drawImage(plat, x, y, 20, 5, null);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, 20,5);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(orien == 1) { // VERTICAL
                // arriba = true;

                if(y < yMax) {
                    arriba = true;
                    abajo = false;
                }

                if(y >= yMax) {
                    abajo = true;
                    arriba = false;
                }

                if(arriba) {
                    y += 3;
                } else {
                    y -= 3;
                }
            }

            if(orien == 2) { // HORIZONTAL
                // der = true;

                if(distancia >= total) {
                    izq = true;
                    der = false;
                }

                if(distancia <= 0) {
                    der = true;
                    izq = false;
                }

                if(der) {
                    x += 3;
                } else {
                    x -= 3;
                }
            }

            paint();

            try {
                sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Seguro que `this.g` no es `null`? Si el stacktrace empieza en esa línea, ese es el problema. En caso contrario, incluye el stacktrace completo.

Comment: @SJuan76 disculpa, no comprendo a que te refieres:(